# RegOpenKeyEx returns ERROR_NOACCESS

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I am trying to read a registy key under windows 7 x64 using the following code:

```
static void ReadRegistryKey(HKEY hkey, TCHAR* path)
{
HKEY hkey2;
TCHAR value[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR data[4096];
const DWORD dataLength = 4096 * sizeof(TCHAR);
const DWORD valueLength = MAX_PATH+1;
DWORD returnval;
DWORD type = 0;

HLOCAL mem = LocalAlloc(LPTR, 260);
char * pc = (char*)mem;
pc++;
wchar_t* pwc = (wchar_t*)pc;
lstrcpy(pwc, path);

// Does key exist?
returnval = RegOpenKeyEx(hkey, pwc, 0 , KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkey2);

if(returnval == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(returnval == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DWORD actualLength = dataLength;
        DWORD actualValueLength = valueLength;

        returnval = RegEnumValueW( hkey2,
                                    i,
                                    value,
                                    &actualValueLength,
                                    NULL,
                                    &type,
                                    (LPBYTE)data,
                                    &actualLength
                                    );

        if(returnval == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("NO MORE KEYS FOUND in %s\n"), path);
            break;
        }
        if(returnval == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
                         // STUFF
        }
   }
}
}
```

When I use KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_32KEY I get the values stored under the 32Bit registry but when I use the code above trying to read the "normal" 64bit registy I get the error code 0x3e6 (ERROR_NOACCESS)

The way i call the method:

```
ReadRegistryKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
```

What can I do to read the 64bit registry values?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running with "Run as Administrator" ?

Comment: Which part gives you access denied? `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` does not give you permissions to use `RegEnumValueW`, but KEY_READ does give that permission as it includes `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`

Comment: I have tried to use administrator rights, but that did not change anything.

RegEnumValueW does not cause the error its RegOpenkeyEx

Comment: Have you tried using `KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY` to open the 64-bit key?

Comment: Yes, I have tried KEY_WOW64_64KEY but it didn't work.

Comment: What are the definitions of `hkey`, `pwc`, and `hkey2`?

Comment: Please see my update of the method above.

Comment: I think the allocation and pointer arithmetic of `pwc` is causing the problem.  Why not pass in path directly into the `RegOpenKeyEx` method?

Comment: Steve, seems you were right. I simply copied this code from the MSDN page I have to admit I didn't really get it and just left it there. Thanks! (If you want the points, simply add this as answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the allocation and pointer arithmetic of `pwc` is causing the problem. Pass in the `path` directly into the `RegOpenKeyEx` function.

It's also worth noting that the `lstrcpy` will cause a buffer overflow if `path` is longer than 260 bytes.  Instead use [StringCchCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms647527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows to give a string copy that will only copy up to the number of bytes available in the destination buffer.